# Alternative of XmlSerializerFormat attribute in wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I am developing a WCF service and using a shared (SearchRequest)  c# model which contains few properties that i am not using . I am using SOAP UI for generating request xml. While generating xml i am getting those properties also which are not used by me and i  don't want those properties because i am not using it. Even though those properties doesn't have [DataMember] attribute .

But when I am removing [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute  from interface and generating request xml from tool , i am not getting those properties .Below is code snippet :

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IWatchListService
{  
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
               UriTemplate = "PerformScan")]
    SearchResponse PerformScan(SearchRequest request);
}
```

I am using WCF intercepters. Now  when i am sending the request from tool the response model is populating correctly but Response tab of the SOAP UI tool show empty response. Again  when i am putting [XmlSerializerFormat] attribute response is  visible in response tab but now those unwanted properties is also coming .

Any alternative of [XmlSerializerFormat] or any suggestion . Thnx

Comment: You might wanna try [DataContractSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) which is by default used by WCF for data transfers.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved : I am using  DataContract attribute on SearchRequest model but what about  IWatchListService interface .

Comment: Not exactly sure why you're wanting to exclude properties - I get that you don't need them, but why not just ignore them?